# Is Maleficent composed of multiple beings or is she just immortal?

Tags: maleficent

In the film "Maleficent", Maleficent talks about her wings in the third person, using the term "they", like a separate entity. She says "My wings were strong and true, they never let me down, not even once.", like they were some person or thing she could rely upon.

> After being cleaved from her torso when Maleficent was in a drug-induced sleep by Stefan, her wings did not die. In fact, they remained alive and well. Sixteen years later, Stefan is now king, and apparently a bit insane as he keeps the wings caged up on display within glass and metal-cross bars, sometimes having "conversations" with them.

Then, later in the film:

> On the day Maleficent arrived to save Aurora, Maleficent's wings flapped violently enough to escape from its cage with the help of Aurora. The wings then flew and attached themselves onto the back of Maleficent, as if they had a mind of their own. Maleficent appeared surprised, indicating she had no awareness this was going to happen.

What is the explanation of this in canon? Is Maleficent composed of multiple beings or entities or is Maleficent simply immortal and no part of her really dies. In the movie, it appears she ages much less so this hints at her immortality. The 3 fairies that raised Aurora did not appear to age at all.

Comment: A lot of this question would be considered major spoilers to anyone who hasn't seen the film. I put those elements in spoiler tags. It's a good question, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### [Maleficent](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Maleficent) is a fairy and as with all fairies from legends, she is immortal unless killed, and vulnerable to cold iron or steel. Maleficent isn't just any fairy, she is the strongest of all the fairies in the [Moors](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Moors) and becomes the protector of her lands.

- It was her vulnerability to steel which made it possible for her wings to be removed and being drugged which kept her from waking while they were being stolen.
- Her wings are not individual creatures, but due to her magical nature, they are a part of her able to move and return to her if she was close enough to them. This is why the wings were bound as they undoubtedly tried to escape once the drug which allowed them to be removed, wore off.
- Her surprise was due to the fact she probably didn't know her wings did not die once removed from her. Not only did they not die, they returned as powerful as ever.
- Maleficent's magical abilities were the strongest in the Moors and it is her magical puissance which allows her to survive and adapt to her wingless state. Her appearance of aging is probably due to the trauma of losing her wings in such a violent fashion.

Comment: I agree - this was more or less what my answer would have been. Similar in nature to how some undead lore maintains body parts still moving/controllable after separation.